# Click inside UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm working with an iOS application. What I'm trying to accomplish,

Let's say the text for the UILabel is "Rikard bla bla bla Rikard".

So in this text I have tagged two people. And when I click on one of them I display a detailed view about that person. So this is working great if I just have one user named Rikard, and it works with multiple too and I can present the detailed view. But my problem is that I don't know which user I clicked on if I have tagged multiple people with the same name. I know I have to go for the ID. Right now I display by name, so it's not that strange that it's not working.

Should I save information in the database in which order the user entered the two tags or how can I ever know who is who?

Please point me in the right direction. The functionality is working great, it's just the logic for who to display when I click. I want to recreate the tagging system that Facebook have when people comment a photo and tag people in it. You can write multiple names there and Facebook will of course know who is who.

***ADDED***

So what I do when I'm creating my tags. I choose from a list of available tags or I can write them. I will always know which tag to save the current comment with. But the problem occurs when I display them in to different parts,

The first part is just a UILabel with all the tags in a row, separated by blank space. Here I know where the user tapped and I can display the detailed view for the with the name.

The second part is all of the text, I can find where the tags are located, on which line and between what pixels on that line. And I know when I click on them.

But what I need is the logic for clicking two tags with the same name in the same UILabel. Should I somehow save the order of how I saved the tags?

Comment: can you edit your post to add some code?  specifically where you are creating your tags

Comment: I don't find code necessary in this case, what I'm looking for is logic. I can describe what I do.

Answer (score 0):

One option that comes to mind is using an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/) in the label. You may add arbitrary attributes to ranges of text using that class, and its [mutable subclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableAttributedString). Thus, you could add a custom attribute to the range of each user's name, and assign for the corresponding value some unique identifier for the user – possibly an `NSNumber` or `NSString` that can be used to retrieve the proper information.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will look into that. Thank you for your time and answer.